# How do I install wifi-driver in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers, firmware

I am completely new to Arch Linux. Yesterday I managed to install it and everything works fine except for the wifi-connection, because there is no driver installed.

I figured out that I need the `iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode` driver.
How can I install the right firmware? I searched the web a lot, but did not find any hint.

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite Radius 14 l40w c115.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The firmware is already in `linux-firmware`. Have a look here:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/

Also, a quick check in my CentOS 7 server shows:

```
ls /lib/firmware/ | grep '3160-17'
iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
```

And this is on kernel: `3.10.0-514`

A quick look here:
https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/linux-firmware/

Also shows that the firmware `iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode` is indeed in the `linux-firmware` package for Arch Linux. So unless you have manually *removed* `iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode` from your installation, it should be in place!

Answer (score 1):

First try enabling kernel mods

An year ago it is in the arch user repository. Install `yay` to use try it out. Unless it is deleted it should be ok

Btw, congratulations on installing arch as a new user.

Answer (score 1):

Freshly installed Arch today on an old Lenovo T500, found the firmware folder was missing in /lib. I had already downloaded the full firmware package from git https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/

1. Extracted the tar file and su - to root in a terminal
2. mkdir -p /lib/firmware
3. run cp -r /linux-firmware-20220913/* /lib/firmware/

Rebooted and WiFi connected without interaction as I had set the profile in nmtui when I was trying to fix the issue.